# QT/QML c++ Program crash on access a QList from QML

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I have 2 classes for datahandling (CGameList and CGame).

I define one GameList (_gamelist) object in qml to work with it.

I have a Listviews with show the the games from this GameList (editGames_open()).

If I click on one entry of this list, it open a new list with a detailed view of this game (editGame_open(index)).

This work works like expected.

Now my problem:
If I go back to the list and try open it again, my program crash (not every time, sometimes its work 20x times).
The crash appear after the call of getGame.

If I use the debugger I can see my CGameList-object looks fine(data a correct + item in my QList are correct), but after this the program crash with a Segmentation Fault.

The callstack show only QQMlData::wasDeleted as last entry.

I think the problem is, that my object is delete, but I cant find this.

I had try to change my QList from QList _games to QList* _games but without success.

One other thing(I think its the same problem):
Sometimes getGame give back a NULL-pointer(although the game is in the list, but the data are wrong).

**cgamelist.h**

```
#ifndef CGAMELIST_H
#define CGAMELIST_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QList>
#include <qfile.h>
#include <QTextStream>
#include <QDir>
#include <QStandardPaths>
#include <QDateTime>


#include <cgame.h>

class CGameList : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(int itemCount READ getItemCount)
public:
    CGameList(QObject *parent = 0);
    Q_INVOKABLE bool addGame(QString name,int layout);
    Q_INVOKABLE int getItemCount() const;
    Q_INVOKABLE void saveGame(int index);
    Q_INVOKABLE void loadGames(bool force=true);
    Q_INVOKABLE CGame* getGame(int i) const;
    Q_INVOKABLE QString getGamename(int i) const;
    Q_INVOKABLE QString getGamedate(int i) const;
    Q_INVOKABLE void delGame(int i);
private:
    QList<CGame*>* _games;
};

#endif // CGAMELIST_H
```

**cgamelist.cpp**

```
CGameList::CGameList(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{
    _games=new QList<CGame*>();
    _games->clear();
}
...
CGame* CGameList::getGame(int i) const
{

   /* CGame*g=new CGame();
    g->setGamename("test");
    return g;*/
    try
    {
        return _games->at(i);
    }
    catch(...)
    {
        return NULL;
    }
}
...
```

**cgame.h***

```
#ifndef CGAME_H
#define CGAME_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QString>
#include <QDateTime>

class CGame : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(QString gamename READ getGamename WRITE setGamename)
    Q_PROPERTY(int itemCount READ getItemCount)
    Q_PROPERTY(int layout READ getLayout WRITE setLayout)
    Q_PROPERTY(int duration READ getDuration WRITE setDuration)
    Q_PROPERTY(QDateTime date READ getDate WRITE setDate)
public:
    CGame(QObject *parent = 0);
    Q_INVOKABLE QString getGamename() const;
    Q_INVOKABLE void setGamename(QString name);
    Q_INVOKABLE int getItemCount() const;
    Q_INVOKABLE int getLayout() const;
    Q_INVOKABLE void setLayout(int layout);
    Q_INVOKABLE int getDuration() const;
    Q_INVOKABLE void setDuration(int duration);
    Q_INVOKABLE QDateTime getDate() const;
    Q_INVOKABLE void setDate(QDateTime date);

    Q_INVOKABLE QString getEvent(int i) const;
    Q_INVOKABLE void addEvent(QString ename,int time,int sec,int duration);

private:
    QString _name;
    int _layout;
    int _duration;
    QList<QString>* _events;
    QDateTime _date;
};

#endif // CGAME_H
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QtQml>

#include "clayoutlist.h"
#include "clayout.h"
#include "clayoutitem.h"
#include "cgame.h"
#include "cgamelist.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
    //QApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    qmlRegisterType<CLayoutList>("STSP.Tag",1,0,"TagLayoutList");
    qmlRegisterType<CLayout>("STSP.Tag",1,0,"TagLayout");
    qmlRegisterType<CLayoutItem>("STSP.Tag",1,0,"TagLayoutItem");
    qmlRegisterType<CGame>("STSP.Tag",1,0,"Game");
    qmlRegisterType<CGameList>("STSP.Tag",1,0,"GameList");
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));

    return app.exec();
}
```

**main.qml**

```js
import QtQuick 2.5
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4
import QtQuick.Dialogs 1.2
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

import STSP.Tag 1.0

ApplicationWindow {
    TagLayoutList {
        id: _layoutlist
    }
    GameList
    {
        id:_gamelist
    }


    visible: true

    MainForm {
        id: mainform
        anchors.fill: parent
    }
    MessageDialog{
        id:info

    }
    ...
    function editGames_open()
    {
        _gamelist.loadGames()
        mainform.p_gameslistmodel.clear()
        var i
        for (i = 0; i < _gamelist.getItemCount(); i++) {

            mainform.p_gameslistmodel.append({
                                                  name: _gamelist.getGamename(i),
                                                  date: _gamelist.getGamedate(i),
                                                  gameindex: i
                                              })
        }
        mainform.p_editgames.delmode=false
        mainform.p_editgames.visible = true
        mainform.p_startmenu.visible=false
    }
    function editGame_open(index)
    {
        mainform.p_eventlistmodel.clear()
        var game={}
        try
        {
        game=_gamelist.getGame(index)
        }
        catch(exc)
        {
            console.log("Serious Error 2 "+exc)
            return
        }

        if(game==null)
        {
            console.log("Reload Games")
            _gamelist.loadGames()
            game=_gamelist.getGame(index)
        }
        if(game==null)
        {
            console.log("Error Game not found")
            return
        }

        var i
        var event
        var events
        var t,s,m,h
        for(i=0;i<game.getItemCount();i++)
        {
            event=game.getEvent(i).split('#')[1]
            //console.log(event)
            events=event.split(',')
            t=events[1]
            s=t%60
            t=(t-s)/60
            m=t%60
            h=(t-m)/60
            mainform.p_eventlistmodel.append({
                                                  name: events[0],
                                                  time: h+":"+(m<10?"0":"")+m+":"+(s<10?"0":"")+s,
                                                  eventindex: i
                                              })
        }
        mainform.p_editgame.gname=game.getGamename()
        t=game.getDuration()
        s=t%60
        t=(t-s)/60
        m=t%60
        h=(t-m)/60
        mainform.p_editgame.gtime=h+":"+(m<10?"0":"")+m+":"+(s<10?"0":"")+s
        mainform.p_editgames.delmode=false
        mainform.p_editgames.visible=false
        mainform.p_editgame.visible=true

    }

    function editGame_back()
    {
        mainform.p_editgame.visible=false
        mainform.p_editgames.visible=true
    }
```

Comment: It's good that you posted code to show the problem, but you omitted enough of it that it's impossible to get it to run. :p You should try narrowing it down to a smaller example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to say without being able to debug your program, but it sounds like QML is [taking ownership](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-data.html#data-ownership) of your `CGame` object:

> When data is transferred from C++ to QML, the ownership of the data always remains with C++. The exception to this rule is when a QObject is returned from an explicit C++ method call: in this case, the QML engine assumes ownership of the object, unless the ownership of the object has explicitly been set to remain with C++ by invoking QQmlEngine::setObjectOwnership() with QQmlEngine::CppOwnership specified.
>
> Additionally, the QML engine respects the normal QObject parent ownership semantics of Qt C++ objects, and will not ever take ownership of a QObject instance which already has a parent.

The simplest solution would be to assign a parent to each `CGame` object before returning it to QML. Alternatively, you can do the following for each object:

```
QQmlEngine::setObjectOwnership(game, QQmlEngine::CppOwnership);
```

Comment: Thx for this tip
I change my code and test ist. Until now I had nor crash and it work like intended.

Comment: Thanks! Adding a parent to my object helped for me as well: no crashes any more.

Answer (score 0):

i think you will create your QList from C++, and put in qml like a contextProperty (with that you dont need declare in qml the class, but you still need register type), but the problem is you need refresh (executing again the sentence of declaration of contextPropertie) for every change in the model, and yes, is better user QObject*.

Maybe is better try use a QmlListProperty (here my case [Use QQmlListProperty to show and modify QList in Qml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19284547/use-qqmllistproperty-to-show-and-modify-qlist-in-qml/19307971#19307971)), in youtube exist other tutorial for use that class), or QAbstractListModel (i don't worked before with that class, but tell me is lightly better in some cases).